# Android large empty storage marked as full (new phone)

Tags: storage

So I purchased this brand new X27 Plus with 64Gb storage, the phone shows 63Gb of free space when checking but I keep getting "your storage is full" errors.

When I plug it as MTP on my computer it actually shows the 64Gb disk as used space while it's empty. When I plug it as USB storage, it divides it as a full 1.25Go G: disk and an unreachable H: disk. I tried to access it with "DIR/A h:-s" and get "the device is not ready".

Any ideas of what's going on and how to get this working ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Isn't it encrypted?

Comment: I added the screenshots, sorry I have nearly 0 skill in such field, I can't tell if it's encrypted or not

Comment: @Phil your device looks to have 4GB storage, not 64GB. Can you share output of `adb shell df -h` and `adb shell ls /dev/block`? Also `adb shell blkid` if it works.

Comment: @Phil troubleshooting `fastboot` problems is not directly related to your original question. It's better to leave the question on-topic or edit it to reflect your new queries. Asking unrelated questions in a single question is against rules.

Comment: I doubt that these screenshots show a X27 Plus device running on Android 9. This looks like some custom ROM running an old (Android 4? - because of the USB storage option which was removed on later versions) version. Adding the strange difference of shown and actual flash memory available I would assume that you bought a forged device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not unlock the bootloader because you will lose warranty.
Check the following command to proof it's a [fake X27 plus](https://youtu.be/MEvaGNc7ER0) or install this [app](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw)

```
adb shell cat /proc/partitions
```

Claim the phone to the seller and get your money back

Comment: according to your fastboot screenshot it is a mt6572_v1 (old SoC model). phone is fake

Comment: Wow thanks, that's exactly my phone, the app reveiled the true specs and I've been refunded, thank you for all your time !